# Running Docker inside a Python app on Heroku?

Tags: python, docker, heroku

I'm using the Docker SDK for Python, and the following code is working as expected locally:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
output = client.containers.run(image="python:3.6.0", command=["redacted"], remove=True)
```

I added docker to my Heroku `requirements.txt` file, but Heroku is not able to connect to Docker. The stack trace is basically connection issues:

```
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572249+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572307+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572308+00:00 app[web.1]: chunked=chunked,
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572308+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572309+00:00 app[web.1]: conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572310+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572310+00:00 app[web.1]: self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572310+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572311+00:00 app[web.1]: self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572311+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572312+00:00 app[web.1]: self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572312+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572312+00:00 app[web.1]: self.send(msg)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572312+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572313+00:00 app[web.1]: self.connect()
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572313+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572313+00:00 app[web.1]: sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572314+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gevent/_socket3.py", line 356, in connect
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572314+00:00 app[web.1]: raise error(result, strerror(result))
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572314+00:00 app[web.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572314+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572315+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572315+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572315+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572315+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572315+00:00 app[web.1]: timeout=timeout
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572316+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572316+00:00 app[web.1]: method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572316+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 403, in increment
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572316+00:00 app[web.1]: raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572316+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572317+00:00 app[web.1]: raise value.with_traceback(tb)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572317+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572317+00:00 app[web.1]: chunked=chunked,
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572317+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572318+00:00 app[web.1]: conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572318+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572318+00:00 app[web.1]: self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572318+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572318+00:00 app[web.1]: self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572319+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572319+00:00 app[web.1]: self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572319+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572319+00:00 app[web.1]: self.send(msg)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572319+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572320+00:00 app[web.1]: self.connect()
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572320+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572320+00:00 app[web.1]: sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572320+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gevent/_socket3.py", line 356, in connect
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572320+00:00 app[web.1]: raise error(result, strerror(result))
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572320+00:00 app[web.1]: urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572321+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572321+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572321+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572321+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572321+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572321+00:00 app[web.1]: return route.call(**args)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572322+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1740, in wrapper
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572322+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = callback(*a, **ka)

2020-08-13T08:12:50.572340+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py", line 868, in create
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572340+00:00 app[web.1]: resp = self.client.api.create_container(**create_kwargs)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572340+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 430, in create_container
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572341+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.create_container_from_config(config, name)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572341+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 440, in create_container_from_config
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572341+00:00 app[web.1]: res = self._post_json(u, data=config, params=params)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572341+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 289, in _post_json
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572342+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._post(url, data=json.dumps(data2), **kwargs)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572342+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572342+00:00 app[web.1]: return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572342+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 226, in _post
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572343+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.post(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572343+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 578, in post
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572343+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572343+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572343+00:00 app[web.1]: resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572344+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572344+00:00 app[web.1]: r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572344+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572345+00:00 app[web.1]: raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
2020-08-13T08:12:50.572345+00:00 app[web.1]: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

How can I run Docker inside a Python app on Heroku? Has anyone had success with this?