# running "docker search" in Heroku via python(flask)

Tags: python, docker, heroku

I'm attempting to search docker hub for images using the command "docker search", via python code.
here is the piece of code for this action:

```
client = docker.from_env()
image_list = client.images.search('ubuntu')
```

running this in the command line works, and also running it via flask locally works.
however, when deploying to heroku, this crashes the site, and the logs say the following:

docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
which basically tells me docker isn't installed on the machine running docker.

I found this question:
[Running Docker inside a Python app on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63401510/running-docker-inside-a-python-app-on-heroku)
but it wasn't answered and basically describes what I need.

any idea what I can do in this situation? thanks!